# Avoid discover services from BLE device during connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Android application with Bluetooth low energy communication, and I need a fast connection with my BLE devices. Discovering services of the device takes 2 seconds, that's a lot for my app, if I connect for first time to the device the services are kept in some cache in the BLE framework, then the next time I try to discover services takes miliseconds, that's fine for my app.

The problem is that if I disconnect from the device for a lnog time or I connect  to another device, the next time I connect to the first device I need to discover the services and takes 2 seconds.

I only connect to one type of devices and the services and characteristics are known.

I tried to use the bounded(pairing) devices, but when I connect to them there is no services saved and I need to discover it again.

Is there any method to save the services and characteristics and keep it in my app so the next time I connect to a device I don't need to discover services?

Comment: Any luck with this? I see similar issue with Android L

Comment: I'd like an answer to this question too. Anyway to avoid the service discovery, always?

Answer (score 4):

You can connect and no need to discover service at the same time. do service discovery when you need service instances.

**Is there any method to save the services and characteristics and keep it in my app so the next time I connect to a device I don't need to discover services?**

You can save `service` and `characteristic` details in `app`. but when you try to read and write characteristics then the `BluetoothGatt` instance should have this detail, and only service discovery adds service data in `BluetoothGatt` Instance.

So you have to do `service` `discovery` in your app at one point of time before using those `services/characteristics`.